# how to nest a label with a imageview in swift 3

Tags: swift, imageview, save, swift3, photo

The following code can take a picture and save it to the photo gallery. This code also features a label that goes over the imageview but its just goes over the top of the image and is not saved on the image. How can I nest the label so that when the photo is saved the text and the image are both in the final photo in the photo gallery.

```
    import UIKit

  class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func camera(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated:  true, completion:  nil)



        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
        label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 222)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = "I'am a test label"
        self.view.addSubview(label)

    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
        image.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        image.image = pickedImage

    }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func save(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image.image!)
    let compressedImage = UIImage(data:  imageData!)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedImage!, nil, nil, nil)


}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should draw the image with text like this：

```
    let str = "I'am a test label" as NSString
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.image!.size)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0)
    image.image!.draw(in: rect)
    //str.draw(in: <#The Rect You want#>, withAttributes: <#Specify The Font And Color Or Other Property#>)
    str.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 40)), withAttributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20), NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.green])
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)
    let compressedImage = UIImage(data:  imageData!)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedImage!, nil, nil, nil)
```

Comment: I dont no what to put in the  //str.draw(in: <#The Rect You want#>, withAttributes: <#Specify The Font And Color Or Other Property#>) part. Can you just give me placement values to put in so I can see some text attached to the picture in the photo gallery?  Thanks

Comment: Just like this `str.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 40)), withAttributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20), NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.green])`

Comment: That did not work. I put your code all under my save button. The photo takes and is saved but there is no text on it.

Comment: I have test the code myself. It works. You can set more breakpoint to see what's wrong